# Enabling TrueColors in Apple MacBook Pro M2 with Alacritty

Tags: macos, command-line, color

I'm trying Alacritty on MBP M2 connected to a Lenovo 4K monitor. I wanted to enable True Colors support as indicated as one of the salient features of the software.

My minimal YAML configuration and setting TERM to alacritty as advised in this Unix.SE post [Why would I set TERM to xterm-256color when using Alacritty?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/597445). In fact I tried [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678901), which didn't work.

```yaml
[shell]
program = "/opt/homebrew/bin/fish"

[font]
size = 15
normal = { family = "Fira Code", style = "Regular" }
bold = { family = "Fira Code", style = "Bold" }
italic = { family = "Menlo", style = "Italic" }

[window]
startup_mode = "Maximized"
dynamic_title = true

[env]
TERM = "alacritty"

[scrolling]
history = 100000

[terminal]
osc52 = "CopyPaste"

[selection]
save_to_clipboard = true
```

I verified that True colors is still not supported by trying out this method as below, from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/604931/112235) and here

[image]

At this point, contradicting to what is indicated here [termstandard/colors](https://github.com/termstandard/colors), it says doing the print below should be in brown color. On my Alacritty terminal it prints

[image]

So my question, is my Alacritty configured to support true colors or not?